# jQuery Isoptope Setting Default Sorting Filter Through URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am wondering what is the issue with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GwBa8/150/

I want to change which category loads by default using different links without having to add extra pages to my site. The last working state is this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GwBa8/128/. The only difference is the following code added to the start of the jQuery.

```
 //e.g. website.com/index/filter/games
  var $criteria = '*';
  var str = window.location.pathname;

  //games
  if (str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('#'))) {
     var $criteria='.'+str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('#'));
} else {
    var $criteria = '*';
}
```

Why does this code stop it working?

I would like to have something like www.website/index#games to load games by default.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @nchaud comment...

```
$(window).load(function(){

 //e.g. website.com/index/filter#games
  var str = document.URL;

     //games
  if ((str.lastIndexOf('#'))!== -1) {
     var $criteria=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('#'));


} else {
    var $criteria = '#all';

}
```

This sets the variable $criteria to the matching id of the link for the category in the navigation.

```
var $container = $('.creations-container');
$container.isotope({
    filter: '*',
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    }
});

$('.creations-filter a').click(function(){
    $('.creations-filter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector,
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
     });
     return false;
    }); 
$($criteria).trigger("click");
```

this clicks on the element with the id in the url

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like (untested!)

```
$(window).load(function(){

  //e.g. website.com/index/filter/games
  var str = window.location.pathname;

  //games
  var criteria=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/'));

  var $container = $('.creations-container');
  $container.isotope({
      filter: '.' + 'criteria',
  }
```

});

Comment: Doesn't work, if I understand you correctly this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/GwBa8/134/ is the output assuming the code upto setting the criteria variable works correctly.

Comment: You're going to have to do some legwork yourself to make it work - it doesn't work until you have this hosted on your website at location website.com/index/filter/games or wherever you've hosted it

Comment: I edited this code slightly and it works! Please "peer review" it and I will accept it as the answer