# How to set Isotope Default Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GwBa8/128/

I would like to set the default filter which is currently

```
filter: '*',
```

on line 4 of the Javascript in the fiddle.

I would like an

```
<a href="example.html"> Games </a>
```

link (located on another page) to load the games filter on default, does anybody know how I could go about doing this??

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of your original question -  [jQuery Isoptope Setting Default Sorting Filter Through URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503489/jquery-isoptope-setting-default-sorting-filter-through-url/21513167)

I've added a comment to your response on that page. The code should work in principle - pls have a look.